# How do I read pagecolumns from the current page

Tags: development, list, object-model, spsite

I know that I have to use

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("SPsite Path");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList contacts = web.Lists["Listname"];
```

if I need to get content of a List, but how do I read data from the pagecolumns of the page I am currently on?

Edit:

```
                    io=0;
                   foreach (SPListItem item in SPContext.Current.ListItem.ListItems)
                {



                    output.Write(item[io] + "|" + io + "<br/>");

                    io++;
                }
```

Does give me: **0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39005A81DBCD88A1A24FA0B25F46F1AEC15500FAC7433996C57149A6320A1777FA6771|0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SPContext.Current.ListItem["ColumnName"]` should do it

Comment: Does give me: 0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39005A81DBCD88A1A24FA0B25F46F1AEC15500FAC7433996C57149A6320A1777FA6771|0

Comment: Please post more of your code - in particulr where that `io` variable comes from, your result is that's the value of the Content Type column, and it's showing a content type of a custom Page Layout.

Comment: Argh.... i just want to access the Pages' columns which are inheriting from my custom Content Type.. The io is just an increasing int.. (started at 0)... ... I have a field called "Contact" in my Content Type and set this column through a field i added in my page-layout.. Now i want to read this field on the page i am in my wp.

Comment: Then have you tried `SPContext.Current.ListItem["Contact"]` ?

Comment: Ya  this works... well.. the listing not but a'm okay with that solution. Thank you.